# Querying database to find a customer?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form for query</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
  include('../connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['Name'])) {
  $name = $_POST['Name'];
}

if(!empty($name)) {

  $sql = "SELECT * from customers where Name = $name";

  $query = mysqli_query($db,$sql)
    or die("Cannot query the database.<br>" . mysql_error());

  $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
  if ($num_rows == 0) {print "There is no record with that id";}

  print "<table align=\"left\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"2\" border=\"0\">\n";

  while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $name = $result["Name"];
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo 'Customer:  '. $name; ?> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<?php
  }
  } else {

?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost/php/find_customer.php" method="post">

<tr>
    <td><b>Enter customer name:  </b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Name" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Submit"></td>
        <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>

<?php
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

So what's supposed to be going on here is I'm searching my database for the user input, which is a name. This worked fine when I was searching by ID, but now when I attempt to search it says "Cannot query the database."

'../connect.php' is the connection to my database, customers is a table in my database and Name is a row within it, I think everything else should be self-explanatory. I really don't understand why it worked with ID but isn't working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around `name`.
Try this:

```php
$sql = "select * from customers where Name = '$name'";
```

Comment: Exactly the problem. Thanks.